# Taxonomy terms follow/unfollow module (even for anonymous users)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, notifications, emails

I want a subscriptions/notifications like module which works for anonymous users too.

Users should be able to subscribe to a taxonomy term, and then be alerted if content is created for that term.

Subscriptions work great but the lack of support for an anonymous user is quite disappointing. I don't get why we can't send a verification mail for any anonyomous user based subscription.

Any Drupal Module which does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my sandbox module
[Total Subscription](https://drupal.org/sandbox/deepakaryan1988/2113077)

This module is in the [Drupal project applications' issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/2172233).

It will provide the functionality as per your requirement.

Comment: Glad you made a module for that, but please post it in more objective way, without chatty and advertisement-like parts. We don't want you to look like a self-promoting spammer. [Sometimes it causes a lot of drama](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122663/225745). Duplicating answers does not help, too. If your module solves couple of problems, please try to also tell how exactly it solves the exact problem in question - a screenshot of appropriate option screen would be welcome, for example.

Comment: Hi Molot,
it has been now published as a full project
http://drupal.org/project/total_subscription.